Masstransit message topology
When configuring the receive endpoint, whilst it is possible to configure a consumer for generic type messages, there doesn't appear to be any way to configure the message topology for a generic type message. The only method on IReceiveEndpointConfigurator is ConfigureMessageTopology<T>(book enabled = true)
Does anyone no away around this?
The only way I can get around this is to use reflection, but that is an ugly solution.

Easy enough to add.

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{messageQueueName}_main", 
                    e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer(getBalanceConsumer, context);

                        // This is the easy way if you know the type in advance
                        //e.ConfigureMessageTopology<GetBalance<HongKong>>(false);

                        Type getBalanceMessage = typeof(GetBalance<>).MakeGenericType(territory);

                        var configureTopologyMethodInfo = typeof(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator)
                                  .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                  .Where(w => w.IsGenericMethod &&
                                         w.Name == nameof(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator.ConfigureMessageTopology)).FirstOrDefault();
                        configureTopologyMethodInfo = configureTopologyMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(getBalanceMessage);

                        configureTopologyMethodInfo.Invoke(e, new object[] { false });

                    });

Obviously using reflection if not very elegant and can lead to broken code if the library is updated...
